# No "noun" in this "direct object"?

Tags: direct-objects

In "I want the following: butter, sugar, and flour" "the following" seems a "direct object", "following" seems like a verb. I thought nouns seem like objects?

Comment: *The following* must be a noun phrase.  We can tell because of the determiner *the*.  I'm not sure what you mean by "nouns seem like objects".  Perhaps you mean "I thought objects had to be nouns"?

Comment: "I thought objects had to be nouns" something like that. A, "noun phrase" seems thought a, "direct object"? It seems, "the" a, "determiner", gets, "following" a "verb" to go into a, "noun phrase", and, or, "direct object", like, maybe, "the smelly"?

Answer (score 1):

An object does not necessarily have to be a noun. They can be nouns, pronouns, phrases, or clauses. Here are some examples:

> - I want **cookies**. (direct object = noun)
> - I want **to work**. (direct object = verb phrase)
> - I want **that**. (direct object = pronoun)
> - I want **you to stand up for yourself**. (direct object = clause)

You can see that a direct object can take many forms. In your sentence, however, it is a noun. More specifically it is an *ing-form* of the verb *to follow* **used as** a noun. You can often use ing-forms as nouns:

> - **The fighting** led to arrests.
> - **Closing up** prevents any more customers from entering your shop.

Note that the ing-forms used as nouns do not necessarily take an article.

If you want to learn more about ing-forms, you can take a look at [this page](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/ing-forms).

Answer (score 1):

"the following" is elliptic and stands for "the following things".  When "the following" is used without "things" we must see it as a noun, meaning everything that follows. Probably used only before enumerations.